# Error in sending data (post) from AJAX to NODEJS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I need to get data sent from ajax to nodejs.
Here is AJAX side:

```
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/a",
  data: { id: "2" },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function fun(json) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
  }
})
```

And In Node:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var quizzController = require('./quizzController')

app.post('/a', function (req,rep) {
  rep.send('ok')
  console.log(req.body.id)
})
app.listen(3000)
```

When I send, I get this error in AJAX side:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/a?                              callback=jQuery111105826120341114538_1490969686792&id=2&_=1490969686793
```

Comment: You should consider adding an error callback (`error: function(error){}`) to your ajax request, and maybe using `console.log()` to show the error in the console. There might be an error server side with your data and you are not catching it.

Comment: also, you don't need to name your success callback function; `success: function(data){}` works fine

Comment: Are you sure the response is JSONP? If you check the console for errors you will hopefully see some information which will help you debug the problem

Comment: I checked the console and the error is the one that I've written in the question. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Is there no description with the error? That's just the URL that was called.

Comment: I displayed the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Show the code where you define/declare your routes?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a POST using JSONP as datatype. You can only do a HTTP/GET. If you have CORS issue, you have to enable cross-origin request sharing in the server side. Something like :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/a",
  type:"POST",
  data: { id: "2" },
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function fun(json) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
  }
})
```